# Read utf-8 using Scanner

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, java.util.scanner

I am having trouble with UTF-8 encoding when using ***Scanner***. Example two lines of my data file:

```
000001 Mėlynas Tadas 63210309683 V 2003/03/17 2016/03/17 
000002 Raudonas Tomas 65505023282 V 2006/01/26 2018/01/26
```

Currently I am using ***Scanner*** to read the text separately instead of the whole line as this is more convenient, but it doesn't read correctly because of the encoding. I've read about using ***InputStream*** etc but I don't want to deal with messy line chopping. Is there a way to use ***Scanner*** with UTF-8?

Comment: User commented under an answer:  

> Ohh wait, I just realised I'm an idiot, since I've added data to my data file and didn't alter the code to read it correctly... – Justin Dec 14 '14 at 21:21

Answer (score 12):

This code snippet might help:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("es", "ES");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
sc.useLocale(loc);
```

Comment: Sadly, it didn't. The problem probably occurs when the data is checked by setters which are called with a constructor when data is being read. As I've made data checks in my constructors, they tell me that the data is bad.

Comment: I am very bad at guessing what your code does :) would you mind sharing it and be more specific?

Comment: I was thinking how do I do this in the most efficient way and ended up uploading the whole project. I hope this helps to understand my problem:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2wRQ2r2rQGhbHotTU51WTFwWWc&usp=sharing

Comment: Ohh wait, I just realised I'm an idiot, since I've added data to my data file and didn't alter the code to read it correctly...

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried, `Scanner myScanner = new Scanner("myFile", "UTF-8");`