# Java - reading String with Scanner giving me weird characters

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How the string is saved:

`<title="<html><center>TURN: Washington's Spies (TV Series 2014– ) - IMDb</center></html>">`

After parsing through the title a bit, just use a simple delimiter for the quote i.e

`useDelimiter("\"")` and using

`lineScanner.next()`, the title I get back is

`TURN: Washington's Spies (TV Series 2014â€“ ) - IMDb`

That's what I get through console and what I see when I set the text of a JLabel. What I want is

`TURN: Washington's Spies (TV Series 2014– ) - IMDb`

How do I avoid this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You should probably be using an XML parser to do complex (or even moderately complex) extraction operations from your HTML string.

Comment: It looks like you're parsing it in the wrong character set - I would *guess* something like it is saved as UTF-8, and you're loading it as ISO-8859-1. Please show how you create `lineScanner`.

Comment: I don't think this question needs any improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `–` character after `TV Series 2014` is the unicode symbol [En dash](http://unicode-table.com/2013/)

Encoded with *UTF-8* this is `E2 80 93`(hex).

It seems like your Scanner does not know he is reading an *UTF-8* encoded string, but thinks it's an *Windows-1252* encoded one so it is reading the 3 chars `E2`(â), `80`(€) and `93`(“):

> How do I avoid this?

Let your `Scanner` read *UTF-8*: [Read utf-8 using Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473513/read-utf-8-using-scanner)

```
lineScanner = new Scanner(/*...*/, "UTF-8");
```