# How to fix problem about encoding in Java?

Tags: java

I have a problem about encoding in Java. When I use Scanner to input a String in Java, My String is wrong.

Example:

- input `Lê`
- result is `L☐`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String(new Scanner(System.in).next());
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: new Scanner("myFile", "UTF-8");

Comment: Yes. I tried it but that was not effect :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read utf-8 using Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473513/read-utf-8-using-scanner)

Comment: Please copy the code as text, not as an image. Also `next()` returns a `String`, so doing `new String(...)` is redundant.

Comment: No it didnt work :(

Comment: The used encoding depends on your operating system and the used console (we.g. Windows cmd, Linux terminal, Netbeans terminal, ...). Which one do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not the problem with **Scanner** class because "System.in" uses the default encoding being used by OS so first you have to test whether you have proper charset defined in your OS for this simply output the hard coded string.

```
System.out.println("Lê");
```

If you have proper charset installed then this will display the same result or else it will display

L?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to read the input bytes as UTF-8??

```
String s = new String(new Scanner(System.in).next().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(s);
```

This solution works for me.

Comment: This may seem to work, but it is more a workaround than a proper solution.